# how to check the return from function

Tags: javascript

i'm new to programming , i don't understand this line if(!validateform(siteName,siteURL)) ,what happens if function return false , will it enter the if condition ???

```
if(!validateform(siteName,siteURL))
      return false;

// Validate Form
function validateForm(siteName, siteUrl){
  if(!siteName || !siteUrl){
    alert('Please fill in the form');
    return false;
  }

  var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var regex = new RegExp(expression);

  if(!siteUrl.match(regex)){
    alert('Please use a valid URL');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: You really should ask this better and search the Internet but: "!" means not - hence if validate form returns false it will enter the "if" scope, without the "!" it will enter only if the method returns true

Comment: if(!validateform(siteName,siteURL))
          return false;

says that if your function returns false then return false.

Answer (score 1):

If the function returns false it will enter the if condition, but if the function returns true it won't enter the if condition. This is because you are using the not operator (!).

The not operator simply makes a boolean true value into a false value and a false to a true value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is an error in the line you want to know about when you're calling a function remember it is case-sensitive. Your function is defined as `validateForm` but you are calling it with `validateform`.

That aside the below snippet is an attempt to explain what the function does during runtime.

in the below snippet

`if(!validateForm(siteName,siteURL))`

what this line does is it calls the function `validateform()` and passes the arguments `siteName` and `siteURL` . The function performs certain validations on the parameters and depending on the outcome of the validating statements(commented below) it returns `true` or `false`. The condition in the if statement `!validateForm(siteName,siteURL)` checks to see if the output of the function is `false` (ie `return false;`). If it is false it will execute the if statement(remember this depends on the parameters passed). You can see the examples in the snippet to see when the statement returns true/false.

```js
function checkURL(siteName, siteUrl) {
  if (!validateForm(siteName, siteUrl)) {
    console.log("invalid name " + siteName);
    console.log("invalid URL " + siteUrl);
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("Site name is valid " + siteName);
    console.log("Site URL is valid " + siteUrl);
  }
}


// Validate Form
function validateForm(siteName, siteUrl) {
  if (!siteName || !siteUrl) { //validating statement 1
    alert('Please fill in the form');
    return false;
  }

  var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var regex = new RegExp(expression);

  if (!siteUrl.match(regex)) { //validating statement 2
    alert('Please use a valid URL');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log("URL and name valid");
checkURL("stackoverflow","https://www.stackoverflow.com");
console.log("URL invalid")
checkURL("stackoverflow","stackoverflow");
console.log("Name not defined");
checkURL(undefined,"https://www.stackoverflow.com");
console.log("URL not defined");
checkURL("stackoverflow",undefined);
```